# Trigger execution problem

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert,after insert,before update,after update) {

//Set of Task IDs
set<ID> tskid = new set<ID>();
//set of WhoIDsto lookup
set<ID> whoIDs = new set<ID>();
//set of WhatIds to update
set<ID> whatIDs = new set<ID>();
//Map of Contact IDs and Contacts
map<ID,Contact> contactMap = new map<ID,Contact>();
//Map of Survey IDs
map<ID,ID> SurveyMap = new map<ID,ID>();

//Get all of the whoIDs of the tasks being inserted/updated
for (task t : trigger.new) {
    if (t.WhoId != null && t.subject.contains ('Contact scored one or more questions')) {
        whoIDs.add(t.whoid);
        whatIDs.add(t.whatid);
        }
    }
system.assert(whoIds.size()>0);

//Populate contactMap with the contact IDs and contact record
for (contact c : [select id from contact where id in : whoIDs]) {
    contactMap.put(c.id,c);
}

   //Populate surveyMap with the survey ids and Contact ID with Most recent     Survey flag = True
     for (Survey__c s : [SELECT id from Survey__c where Most_Recent_NPS_Survey__c = TRUE and contact__c in: whoIDs]){
    surveyMap.put(s.id,s.id);
    }
    //system.assert(surveyMap.size()>0);

for (task t: trigger.new) {
    if (t.whatid == null && surveyMap.containsKey (t.whoID)){
            for ( Id id: surveymap.keyset()){         
            t.whatID = surveyMap.get(id);
            }
            system.debug('surveyrecord Id: ' + t.whatId);
        }
    }
```

Trigger is not executing What could be the problem.

I wanted to make sure it works before using the handler and trigger actions apex.
I think there is something wrong in my code.

Comment: Put in `System.Debugs('');` how far is it getting?  Also the Subject.Contains is risky, can you trigger this off anything else besides a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see several problems with your code, but I'm not sure which is the cause of the problem. Let's go a few things.

## Assert In Live Code

Don't do this. Ever. Assert methods are meant for unit tests, and they always cause fatal, uncatchable exceptions. Imagine all of your users unable to create or edit tasks ever again, while you frantically try to deploy code that will allow them to do so.

## Map of Id to same Id

This is not what you wanted. You need to be able to map the Id to something else. Basically, you're randomly selecting a Survey Id when any contact matches the criteria.

## Modifying Read-Only Records

In an after insert or after update context, Trigger.new is immutable and read-only. Use only before insert and before update.

## Overly Complicated

This part is easy. You're making a mountain out a molehill. A very small one, at that. Here's basically what what you apparently need:

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert, before update) {
    Set<Id> completedIds = new Set<Id>();
    Task[] scoredTasks = new Task[0];
    for(Task record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.WhoId != null && record.Subject != null &&
           record.Subject.contains('Contact scored one or more questions')) {
            scoredTasks.add(record);
            completedIds.add(record.WhoId);
        }
    }
    if(scoredTasks.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    Map<Id, Id> contactToSurveys = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for(Survey__c record: [SELECT Contact__c FROM Survey__c WHERE Most_Recent_NPS_Survey__c = TRUE AND Contact__c IN :completedIds]) {
        contactToSurveys.put(record.Contact__c, record.Id);
    }
    for(Task record: scoredTasks) {
        record.WhatId = contactToSurveys.get(record.WhoId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant , as always. N.B. `Task.Subject` is not a required field in Schema so `contains()` could blow up

Comment: @cropredy I never really thought that Subject wasn't required, since it basically serves as the "name" field for a task. Well, on that note, I went ahead and added the check for it.

Comment: imagine my surprise when I learned that `Opportunity.AccountId` wasn't a required field either. BTW - do we throw you a party when you hit 100K?

Comment: @cropredy the schema always teaches us something new. Or something old; I think I used to know that Subject isn't actually required, but it's been some years. As far as the party goes, I don't think I'd be surprised if I showed up at DF16 and something happened.